# In my laravel blog website, i want to display post author as the logged in admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've been having issues displaying author of a post. I created a one to many relationship between admin and post. But in my view (post.blade.php) one admin is showing in all posts as an author rather than the respective admins who created the post. It only assigns the newest admin as the author to all other posts made by different admins, how do i get rid of this error please?.[When i die and dumb post, it shows the admin_id perfectly][1]

[This is my post blade][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3UU3.png //When i die and dumb posts it shows the correct admin_id
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3cOS.png// This is my post blade
[This is my post model][1]

[This is my post table][2]

[Post controller for user][3]

[AdminPostController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwaAj.png//AdminPOstController)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmYLJ.png//Post model
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXVc.png//Post table
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/34aK0.png// PostController for user side

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide the code as text.

Comment: Please do not post the code as images. Just edit your post and add the necessary models, migrations and controller in order the others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can a post have multiple admins or should it only be one at a time?

Comment: Okay, @RossWilson an admin can have multiple posts but a post has one author, which is the admin

Comment: class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function post(Request $request, post $post, category $category)
    {
        $posts = post::all();
        $postss = post::where('status', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->limit(1)->get();
     $categories = $category::all();

        //dd ($post);
        return view('user/layout/post', compact('post', 'posts','categories', 'postss'));
    } } This is my PostController for the frontend side